# How to get MDC in a OkHttp request interceptor?

Tags: java, spring-boot, okhttp

In a spring-boot-3 application with okhttp3, I try to write an interceptor to add a correlation id header to all my requests but I am not able to acces the MDC context from my okhttp interceptor: it is always empty.

How can i correctly setup OkHttpClient and/or interceptor so that the MDC context is propagated to the interceptor?

My OkhttpClient is declared:

```
@Bean
public OkHttpClient okHttpClient() {
    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(new LoggerInterceptor())
        .build();
}
```

My interceptor is declared:

```
@Slf4j
public class LoggerInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        log.info("MDC {}", MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()); // <==== KO MDC context is null
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

And my calls are done like that:

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<Optional<JsonNode>> getEvent(String eventId) {
    log.info("MDC {}", MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()); // <==== OK my MDC context is correct
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(rsvpServicesProperties.getResource() + "/v2/events/" + eventId)
            .tag(MDC.getCopyOfContextMap())
            .build();
    
    CompletableFuture<T> futur = new CompletableFuture<>();
    okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            futur.completeExceptionally(new IOException("Error occurred while getting " + request.url().url() + ": " + e.getMessage(), e));
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            try {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    futur.complete(mapper.map(response.body().bytes()));
                }
                futur.complete(mapper.map(null));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IOException("Exception occurred while mapping response of " + request.url().url() + ": " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    });
    return futur;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Enqueued calls execute on a different thread from the enqueuer.

Some options:

- User Request.Builder.tag to supply MDC stuff when you create the request
- Build your own Call.Factory implementation that decorates OkHttpClient and captures MDC info in newCall().

Comment: Request.Builder.tag need to be called everytime a new Request is made, this is not better than adding everywhere in my codebase `Request.Builder.header("x-correlation-id", MDC.get("correlationId"))`.  Do you have any example of implementing a custom Call.Factory ?